# How to identify the cause of a crash in the context menu

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, crash, context-menu

When I right-click on a file in an open-dialog it makes the underlying application crash "once-in-a-while". This happens in many applications such as Total Commander and Visual Studio . The application don't crash each time, but when they do it is before I click any item in the context-menu. I looked at the call-stack and I see nothing interesting to pinpoint what is the cause of the crash. This started to happens a couple of months ago so I don't know what I could have installed that causes this problem.
My context menu contains items related to TortoiseHg, TortoiseSVN, SandBoxie and a couple of other usual apps like 7-Zip, etc.
I never noticed any crash when using the context menu directly from Windows Explorer but I think it could be crashing more silently than other apps.

How can I identify which item of the context menu is causing these crashes ? Is there any crash log I could look at somewhere ?

**Update:** I have uninstalled all applications (Avast, VLC, etc.) adding items in the context menu and the crashes still happen. I noticed that it is a lot easier to reproduce the crashes in some apps (Total Commander) than other (IPLab), not sure why.

**Update 2:** The compressed dump file is now available [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=7C626B0779062C74!465). It is based on the IPLab application available [here](http://www.aforgenet.com/projects/iplab/downloads.html).

Comment: create dumps and share them (compress them to RAR/7z to reduce the size!!!!!!) : http://pastebin.com/zKuJvw57

Comment: @magicandre1981: I have a full crash dump (92MB, compressed). I will upload it nest Tuesday because for now I have a limited internet connection and cannot upload such a big file...

Comment: @Ramhound no, this is an usermode application crash. BlueScreenViewer is here useless.

Comment: How did you make a crashdump?!

Comment: @Nakilon: It seems like magicandre1981's link isn't good anymore. I suggest you take a look at the official documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181.aspx The reg file from magicandre1981 was simply modifying these registry keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash file uploaded has the following information inside:

```
0:014> .exr -1
ExceptionAddress: 000007fef2dabf80 (<Unloaded_SugarSyncVFSNamespace64.dll>+0x000000000001bf80)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000008
   Parameter[1]: 000007fef2dabf80
Attempt to execute non-executable address 000007fef2dabf80
```

It seems that the crash is related to [Sugar Sync](https://www.sugarsync.com/).

```
0:014> lm vm *Sugar*
start             end                 module name

Unloaded modules:
000007fe`f2d90000 000007fe`f2de5000   SugarSyncVFSNamespace64.dll
    Timestamp: Tue Nov 05 05:51:38 2013 (5278795A)
    Checksum:  000471D3
    ImageSize:  00055000
```

The version you're using is from November 2013. Maybe there's a newer one available (couldn't figure out from the website).

I'm using [WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx) to analyze the crash dump.

Commands used:

```
.symfix d:\debug\symbols
.reload
.exr -1
lm vm *Sugar*
```

Explanation of the commands:

- Make sure the symbols will be downloaded from Microsoft
- Force a reload of the symbols to make sure they are up to date
- Show the last exception record
- Show detailed information about the DLL given in the exception address

I think you could use similar commands in VS2012 if you enter them in the Immediate Window, but I'm not too familiar with it.

Comment: Cool ! This is weird, SugarSync is installed but it's not even running. I guess it is called for the icon overlays. Now, could you explain the "how" you got this result ? When loading the dump file in VS2012 I don't see anything you're showing in your answer.

Comment: @rold2007: Updated my answer