# Windows - Explorer.exe crashing when manipulating folders

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, crash

I've got an issue on my Windows Seven SP1 computer, for some unknown reason, the `explorer.exe` process crashes really often when I'm manipulating the folders, especially using paint but not only. (renaming file, opening file, or folders, basically using the explorer folder interface I'd say, couldn't find exactly what triggers this)

I don't know where the error comes from, I only have this error logs to show: (french)

```
Signature du problème :
  Nom d’événement de problème:  BEX64
  Nom de l’application: explorer.exe
  Version de l’application: 6.1.7601.17567
  Horodatage de l’application:  4d672ee4
  Nom du module par défaut: SugarSyncVFSNamespace64.dll_unloaded
  Version du module par défaut: 0.0.0.0
  Horodateur du module par défaut:  5278795a
  Décalage de l’exception:  000007feef14bf80
  Code de l’exception:  c0000005
  Données d’exception:  0000000000000008
  Version du système:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Identificateur de paramètres régionaux:   1036
  Information supplémentaire n° 1:  2264
  Information supplémentaire n° 2:  2264db07e74365624c50317d7b856ae9
  Information supplémentaire n° 3:  c4b1
  Information supplémentaire n° 4:  c4b1aa6be96bfe3a6e0a87e7aae4c7de

Lire notre déclaration de confidentialité en ligne :
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x040c

Si la déclaration de confidentialité en ligne n’est pas disponible, lisez la version hors connexion :
  C:\WINDOWS\system32\fr-FR\erofflps.txt
```

The *Nom du module par défaut:* which is here `SugarSyncVFSNamespace64.dll_unloaded` is sometimes something else, last time I checked it was something to do with `dropbox64.dll`, so I stopped the dropbox process so it's not loaded on startup. But as I thought it didn't solve the problem at all.

I have no idea what's causing this, and I don't know how to solve it neither... Do you have any clue?

I'm thinking about upgrading the computer to Windows 8.1, hoping it would somehow solve the issue in the process.

Comment: POssibly related:
http://superuser.com/questions/708936/how-to-identify-the-cause-of-a-crash-in-the-context-menu

Might try uninstalling SugarSync.

Comment: After a few months, it seems indeed that that was the issue. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but it's easy to test: set Windows Explorer to open each instance as a separate process. See http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-to-launch-windows-explorer-as-a-separate/29ea82db-5f2b-40da-a855-8a43983c15c7
and http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/run-windows-explorer-folders-in-a-separate-process-to-prevent-crashes-and-system-freeze/

Comment: Interesting, it is not a viable solution but I didn't know that was possible. (system with less than 4Go RAM, and would crash the current explorer window anywa, so, kind of a workaround but not a solution)